# NGINX issue cannot access root

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-config

I have setup nginx(non docker container) on host machine

```
server {

    listen 443;
    server_name 1.0.0.0.5;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf/privateKey.key;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
    proxy_send_timeout 600;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    send_timeout 600;
        location /app{
        rewrite ^/app(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://12x.31.0.121:8100;
 }
}
```

docker container running on port 8100
command:
docker run -d -p 8100:1905 b0abf8a52b08

When I try to access the website it is not able to load the static files. In this scenario how do I define root in NGINX or something else needs to be done?

Comment: how does your static file path look like?

Comment: static files are .css, .js, bower_components, image, etc

Comment: I mean your expected url path to those files

Comment: it is expecting ->https://eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/app/Image/data7.png but getting ->https://eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/Image/data7.png

Answer (score 0):

> it is expecting ->eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/app/Image/data7.png
>   but getting ->eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/Image/data7.png

That's `rewrite ^/app(.*) /$1 break;` striping the url, it cuts out the `/app`. Remove it and it will be good to go.

Comment: did you restarted nginx?